# Is the waves and signal dangerous for human at the airports?

Tags: commercial-aviation, airport

Waved like VHF , UHF and other themes like radio or something ....

Comment: Can you be more clear about your question?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about aviation but rather about biology and physics.

Comment: In favour of the question: airports are places of extraordinarily heavy em load with navaids, radios, radars and huge amounts of people using their personal comms...

Comment: Related: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/65274/23223

Comment: I feel like it's not on topic. The question here is "Are radio waves harmful to health, at the levels found at airports?" We may have some idea of the level of radio waves found at airports, but the other part of the question is totally off topic.

Answer (score 1):

No. To people at the airport, the electromagnetic radiation from various sources relating to aviation (or anything else) is **not** dangerous.

Any electromagnetic radiation is, with enough intensity, possibly dangerous, even instantly lethal, but you can rest assured, that such intensities are not present anywhere a normal person has access to.

Comment: I disagree, weather radars are dangerous to ground crew and require specific procedures to mitigate said danger.

Comment: @AEheresupportsMonica hence "...anywhere a normal person has access to." I'm perfectly aware that some radars can fry your nuts if you manage to sneak close to one (I'm familiar with one case), but that's why access near them is limited.

Comment: thank you so much 